# How can I add a folder to "allowed_resources" in resource_config.json?

Tags: magento

I'm testing out using the database for media storage in Magento, as described here: http://www.aschroder.com/2013/04/actually-running-magento-on-amazons-elastic-beanstalk-cloud-platform/

It works fine for catalog product images. It even works through Cloudfront, as long as I explicitly include "/get.php" in the address. However, one module we use stores images in media/custom/Skitterslideshows. Magento cannot retrieve any of those images from the database.

If I put the file into the file system in that folder, I can get the image through www.domain.com/media/custom/Skitterslideshows/image.jpg.

But I cannot get it through www.domain.com/get.php/media/custom/Skitterslideshows/image.jpg.

It seems that get.php cannot access folders unless they are listed as "allowed_resources" in var/resource_config.json

My resource_config.json contains the following:

{"media_directory":"/var/app/current/media","allowed_resources":["css","css_secure","js","favicon","email","wysiwyg","catalog","custom_options","dhl","captcha","xmlconnect"],"update_time":"1"}

If I place a file in one of the listed folders, I can get to it through get.php, even though it is not in the database. I tried editing resource_config.json to include "custom" but it does nothing, and the file just gets overwritten the next time I use get.php.

I guess my question is how can I add "allowed_resources"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the config.xml:

```
<config>
    <default>
        <system>
            <media_storage_configuration>
                <allowed_resources>
                    <custom_folder>custom</custom_folder>
                </allowed_resources>
            </media_storage_configuration>
        </system>
    </default>
</config>
```

Comment: Nailed it! I can now access images in the file system in the custom folder, and I can also access images in the database. I'm probably going to end up using NFS to share images instead of the database, but this is good to know. By any chance, does anyone know if it is possible to force magento to synchronize the file system again with the database (to be clear, move new images that have been placed in the file system by me - or something like magmi - into the database). Thanks again.

Comment: Happily this also works in `app/etc/config.xml` which is useful if you need to sync images not specific to any module.